# Security flaws to Apple iPad and iPhone via PDFs?

Tags: iphone, security, ipad

Do any SO users know anything about these security flaws that have emerged from the German government of all people?

http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2010/aug/05/apple-security-weakness-ipad-iphone

Is it possible to understand what sort of vulnerabilities this type of hack could have (e.g. on debit/credit cards?)

Comment: This question is best suited for superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [buffer overflow](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Buffer_overflow) vulnerability that affects the iPad/iPhone/iPod Touch.  It is triggered by viewing a specially crafted PDF file and gives the attacker complete and total control over the system.  In fact the attacker will have more control over the system than the user,  or any app developer.  The attacker will be able to obtain any and all information stored on the device,  this includes credit card number and passwords.   The attacker can install a backdoor and access the device any time it is connected to the internet.

Apple has a bad history of security. To metigate this issue you should avoid opening pdf's until you have applied the iOS 4.1 patch.  Expect more vulnerabilities like this in the future.